# Small bug in my recursive quicksort

Tags: java, recursion, quicksort

I'm trying to implement a recursive quicksort.

Half the time this code sorts my array correctly, but sometimes 1 or 2 numbers are out of place.

```
//accesses quicksort  
public int[] quicksort(int[] toBeSorted) {
    int[] sorted = qSort(toBeSorted, 0, toBeSorted.length);
    return sorted;
}

//performs quicksort algorithm recursively
public int[] qSort(int[] toBeSorted, int left, int right){
    int i; 
    int lastsmall;
    int holdThis;
    if (left < right) {
        lastsmall = left;       
        for (i = left; i < right; i++){
            if (toBeSorted[i] < toBeSorted[left]) {
                lastsmall = lastsmall + 1;
                holdThis = toBeSorted[i];
                toBeSorted[i] = toBeSorted[lastsmall];
                toBeSorted[lastsmall] = holdThis;     
            } 
        }
        holdThis = toBeSorted[left];
        toBeSorted[left] = toBeSorted[lastsmall];
        toBeSorted[lastsmall] = holdThis;
        qSort(toBeSorted, left, lastsmall - 1);
        qSort(toBeSorted, lastsmall + 1, right);
    }
    return toBeSorted;
}
```

Comment: Input and expected output/nonexpected output iss..?

Comment: input is an array of randomly generated positive integers, expected output is the array in sorted order (right now a couple are out of order).

Comment: Mind if i suggest another method?

Comment: Go for it. Recursion is important though.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Mergesort algorithm](http://www.toves.org/books/java/ch20-sort/index.html).

Comment: @UnknownOctopus I don't think introducing the Mergesort algorithm to him when he's trying to implement the Quicksort is going to be helpful. No doubt  that the mergesort is a good sorting algorithm as well, but that's probably not what he wants in this case.

Comment: @Gosu true, i just wanted to throw it out there.

Comment: @UnknownOctopus Not an issue at all, I like mergesort more than quicksort myself. I find it easier to understand :P

Comment: @UnknownOctopus Thanks anyhow! I'm trying a merge sort as well, so your effort was not wasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed

```
qSort(toBeSorted, left, lastsmall - 1);
qSort(toBeSorted, lastsmall + 1, right);
```

to

```
qSort(toBeSorted, left, lastsmall);
qSort(toBeSorted, lastsmall + 1, right);
```

and it works with my test arrays. (lastsmall needs to be included, if I recall correctly)

**Complete code:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class __QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // This didn't work with original code
        int[] toBeSorted = new int[]{5, 9, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1, 8, 2};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(quicksort(toBeSorted)));

        toBeSorted = new int[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(quicksort(toBeSorted)));

        toBeSorted = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(quicksort(toBeSorted)));

        toBeSorted = new int[]{9, 1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5, 777, 999, 888};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(quicksort(toBeSorted)));
    }

    // accesses quicksort
    public static int[] quicksort(int[] toBeSorted) {
        int[] sorted = qSort(toBeSorted, 0, toBeSorted.length);
        return sorted;
    }

    // performs quicksort algorithm recursively
    public static int[] qSort(int[] toBeSorted, int left, int right) {

        int i, lastsmall, holdThis;
        if (left < right) {
            lastsmall = left;
            for (i = left; i < right; i++) {
                if (toBeSorted[i] < toBeSorted[left]) {
                    lastsmall = lastsmall + 1;
                    holdThis = toBeSorted[i];
                    toBeSorted[i] = toBeSorted[lastsmall];
                    toBeSorted[lastsmall] = holdThis;
                }
            }

            holdThis = toBeSorted[left];
            toBeSorted[left] = toBeSorted[lastsmall];
            toBeSorted[lastsmall] = holdThis;

            qSort(toBeSorted, left, lastsmall);
            qSort(toBeSorted, lastsmall + 1, right);
        }

        return toBeSorted;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 777, 888, 999]
```

Note:

- {5, 9, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1, 8, 2} didn't work for the original code, you can try it.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! I knew i was overlooking something minor, I just had no idea what it was.